# Problem when selecting MySQL stored procedure to populate datatable in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, mysql, visual-studio, tableadapter

I am looking to populate a datatable with a MySQL stored procedure in Visual Studio. So I do the usual and add a TableAdapter to the DataSet and begin to fill in the details.

I create the connection string, which tests fine and returns all the stored procedures, then I go to populate by stored procedure. I click on the Select combobox and select the stored procedure I want to use for the population. Once I click on it the dialogs and datatable disappear and it goes back to the usual dataset screen.
[image]

What is happening and what can I do to stop it?! I have tested the stored procedure and it works as expected.

EDIT: Just tried other stored procedures and they are working fine...What could be going wrong?!

Comment: I would add a bounty if I could but can't find the option. :(

Comment: Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.

Comment: Ah right...Need it quicker than that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I realised that there was 2 columns in the SELECT statements that had the same alias. Re-aliased (real word?!) the column and everything works now.